# Can I use the same textdomain in two separate plugins?

Tags: plugins, localization

I have two plugins lets name them PluginA and PluginB. Both are part of the same project I want to internationalize the text.

The question is if I use same textdomain 'myplugin' but make two files one in PluginA and other in PluginB and load both using

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', from PluginA )
load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', from PluginB )
```

is that OK, or it overwrites the locales.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use different and specific textdomains, see »[Text Domains Across Multiple Plugins & Themes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/98963/22534)« for more information.

Comment: but what if I have 40% of the string same in both plugins. Shall I use same domain and translate it in one plugin

Answer (score 0):

In simple words "NO" it is not recommended until one plugin is not a subset of another plugin.

If you want multi-language use different.

Thanks,

Vee